# How to install Web8.5 to AWS EC2 with suppored .NET version?

Tags: web8.5, installation

I'll install Web8.5 into AWS EC2.

But.NET framework version becomes a problem.

Web 8.5's recommended OS and .NET version is following.

- Windows Server 2016
- .NET 4.6.2

But when creating Windows Server 2016 on EC2 from AMI, .NET 4.7 has already installed.
Also, SDL says Web8.5 doesn't support .NET 4.7. 
EC2's AMI is updated continuously so AMI that.NET 4.6.2 is installed has already disappeared.
(Even if such AMI exists, it's difficult to find it)

I found Windows update KB3186568, which upgrades .NET to 4.7, is installed the EC2 Windows Server,
but could not uninstall.

If Web8.5 could not be used with .NET 4.7, it's impossible to use EC2 as CMS server practically.

Does anyone use EC2 as Web 8.5's server?

How can I install supported version(.NET 4.6.2) to EC2 Server?

If someone uses EC2 as Web 8.5's server, how is it possible to prepare supported environment(.NET 4.6.2)?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - **SDL Web 8.5** all the prerequisites are shipped with installer setup file itself, It will install **4.6.2 Framework** also installer will do that but the machine will reboot after installing the DOT NET Framework and then SDL installer will start again for rest of the installation.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.Does installer install 4.6.2, even if 4.7 has already been installed?

Comment: Yes. It should, it's possible to keep multiple versions when it's required we can control in web app config.

Comment: It's complicated to figure out which .NET version is installed, but I think old version isn't installed if 4.7 has already installed. SDL's answer to this issue is something like that 'SDL supports the environment even if .NET version is 4.7, but if problem occurs and the problem is caused by difference of .NET version, SDL might not support it.' Be careful about .NET version when using AWS.